# Does Ising model belong to the field of strongly correlated systems?

Tags: condensed-matter

How to make a judgement that whether a problem is within the field of strongly correlated systems? Do classical problems (not quantum mechanical) belong to this field?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a theoretical viewpoint that is strongly biased by my own research interest. Roughly speaking, I describe a system as strongly correlated if mean-field theory fails to predict the correct result. By mean-field theory, I mean any approximation in which one assumes that some correlation function between two randomly fluctuating quantities can be factorised as
$$ \langle A B \rangle \approx \langle A \rangle \langle B \rangle, $$
where $\langle\cdot\rangle$ denotes a statistical average with respect to a probability distribution or quantum state. If this approximation fails, then statistical or quantum correlations between the observables $A$ and $B$ are too strong to neglect. Obviously, depending on your system and the quantity you are interested in calculating, mean-field theory may or may not predict the correct result. Therefore there is a degree of subjectivity here.

This idea can apply to quantum many-body systems such as spin systems (e.g. [Heisenberg model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_model_%28quantum%29)) and classical stochastic many-body systems (e.g. the [simple exclusion process](http://www.lps.ens.fr/~derrida/PAPIERS/1998/altenberg-1998.pdf)).

Comment: @hlew I wasn't referring to the classical statistical mechanics model. I was referring to the quantum Ising Hamiltonian: $$ H = \sum\limits_{\langle jk\rangle} \sigma^x_j\sigma^x_k $$ and variants thereof, where $\sigma^x$ is the Pauli spin operator. I've removed the reference to the Ising Hamiltonian from my answer to avoid confusion. Cheers.

Comment: @hlew I'm afraid I don't know a huge amount about the classical Ising model, but according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_field_theory#Ising_Model) the mean-field treatment predicts a ferromagnetic phase transition in one-dimension, when it is known that there is none from the [exact solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Basic_properties_and_history). So I would describe the 1D classical Ising model as a strongly correlated system.