# Atoms or molecules as strongly correlated systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, molecules, density-functional-theory

Electrons in atoms or molecules are of course correlated, in the sense that the many-electron wave function is not a Slater determinant. However, in my personal impression, the Hartree-Fock approximation or the density-functional theory often works reasonably well for atoms and molecules.  Therefore, the question is, is there any atom or molecule in which the electrons are strongly correlated and defy simple approximations?

Comment: You are aware or not through the exchange and direct potentials, the electrons in the Hartree-Fock method do indeed experience forces from one another? And the simple fact that each electron has a unique, non-overlapping wavefunction means they _kind of_ correlate - if an electron is measured to be in one orbital, all the others will not be in that orbital. Of course not all wavefunctions are a slater determinant, but if that's what you're calling "correllations", I don't think it's actually true that the electrons in an atom are highly correlated.

Comment: @AXensen You are probably referring to Fermi correlation (the detection probability of same-spin electrons being zero around the same point of space), which is just a simple consequence of the Pauli principle. Since every antisymmetric many-electron wave function trivially has this kind of correlation (even HF), people usually do not mean this, when they speak about correlation. Instead, they mean Coulomb correlation, which is by definition everything not covered by the single-determinantal mean-field approach (which can be a lot; see my answer).

Comment: I'd like to mention another problem of correlation/coupling, which occurs at conical intersections(CI) in molecules. The Born-Oppenheimer approximation fails at a CI and nonadiabatic coupling can no longer be neglected. Describing the electronic structure at such points and in its vicinity is still challenging. And it is not just some "exotic problem". Conical intersection are often relevant for processes that occur after photo-excitation of a molecule and can determine the how energy is redistributed. Single determinant methods are usually insufficient in this case and give poor results.

Answer (score 10):

As you correctly say, the wave function of an atom/molecule cannot be written as a single Slater-determinant, it can only be expanded in the basis of determinants:
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}c_i|\Phi_i\rangle \ .
$$
If the exact wave function can be well represented by a single dominant determinant plus small corrections (say $|c_1|\approx1$, $|c_i|\ll1$ for $i>1$), then the system is said to be weakly correlated, and the Hartree-Fock approximation is a good starting point (closed-shell atoms and closed-shell molecules around their equilibrium geometry being the typical examples).
The small corrections of the wave function and the energy can be included via Many-Body Perturbation Theory (MBPT), or an approximate resummation of MBPT (as done in e.g. Random Phase Approximation or Coupled Cluster).

However, to describe e.g. chemical reactions one should be able to compute the (say) ground state energy of molecules for various configurations of nuclei, including configurations where covalent bonds are broken (like when two fragments of a molecule become separated by a very large distance). Such a system cannot even be approximately described by a separable wave function, it is a true linear combination of multiple determinants having roughly the same weight in the expansion. The simplest example is probably the H$_2$ molecule. In its minimal basis model, the (restricted) Hartree-Fock determinant
$$
|\Phi_{\text{RHF}}\rangle=|\sigma_g^+\bar{\sigma}_g^+\rangle
$$
is built from orbitals expanded over atom-centered $1s$ functions:
$$
|\sigma_g^+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1+S_{AB})}}\left(|1s_A\rangle+|1s_B\rangle\right) \ \ \ , \ \ \ 
|\sigma_u^+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1-S_{AB})}}\left(|1s_A\rangle-|1s_B\rangle\right) \ .
$$
The bar denotes a spin orbital with $\downarrow$ spin, and $S_{AB}=\langle 1s_A|1s_B\rangle$. Around equilibrium bond distance, this model works pretty well, and it correctly predicts the creation of the covalent bond as a consequence of the electrons being delocalized over the atomic sites. On the other hand, in the limit of infinite separation, the exact wave function should look like
$$
|\Psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|1s_A\bar{1s}_B\rangle+|1s_B\bar{1s}_A\rangle\right) \ ,
$$
simply mirroring the fact that the two electrons are localized around different atoms (no ionic configuration like $|1s_A\bar{1s}_A\rangle$ is present which would correspond to both electrons localized on the same site).
This is a strongly correlated system, since detection of "electron 1" drastically alters the detection probability of "electron 2":
$$
\rho(\boldsymbol{r}_1,\boldsymbol{r}_2)=
\chi^2_{1s,A}(\boldsymbol{r}_1)\chi^2_{1s,B}(\boldsymbol{r}_2)+
\chi^2_{1s,A}(\boldsymbol{r}_2)\chi^2_{1s,B}(\boldsymbol{r}_1) \ .
$$
We used that $\chi_{1s,A}(\boldsymbol{r})\chi_{1s,B}(\boldsymbol{r})=0$ in the infinite separation limit.
You can check by simple substitution, that the RHF wave function fails in this limit (to make things simple, note that $S_{AB}=0$ for infinitely distant nuclei), as it does contain spurious ionic configurations, hence completely misses the localization of electrons:
$$
|\Phi_{\text{RHF}}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}
\left[\sqrt{2}|\Psi\rangle+
|1s_A\bar{1s}_A\rangle+|1s_B\bar{1s}_B\rangle
\right] \ ,
$$
$$
\rho_{\text{RHF}}(\boldsymbol{r}_1,\boldsymbol{r}_2)=
\frac{1}{2}\rho(\boldsymbol{r}_1)\rho(\boldsymbol{r}_2)=
\frac{1}{2}\left[
\rho(\boldsymbol{r}_1,\boldsymbol{r}_2)+
\chi^2_{1s,A}(\boldsymbol{r}_1)\chi^2_{1s,A}(\boldsymbol{r}_2)+
\chi^2_{1s,B}(\boldsymbol{r}_1)\chi^2_{1s,B}(\boldsymbol{r}_2)
\right] \ .
$$
Conversely, if you invert the orbital expansion formulae, and plug them in the exact wave function, then you can see that $|\Psi\rangle$ is the equal weight combination of the Slater determinants $|\sigma_g^+\bar{\sigma}_g^+\rangle$ and $|\sigma_u^+\bar{\sigma}_u^+\rangle$ (actually, it turns out to be one of the famous Bell states displaying maximal bipartite entanglement). Our choice to use a single determinant for this extremely multi-determinantal system gives rise to an abnormally high energy (the RHF energy does not tend to the sum of two hydrogen atom energies), and it introduces (quasi-)degeneracy in the orbital energy spectrum, rendering the MBPT expansion built on the RHF determinant violently divergent:

[image]

This means that our bad results cannot be simply corrected. It is not hard to imagine that more complex molecules show very similar pathologies when their covalent bonds become stretched (just think of the three covalent bonds of N$_2$). See e.g. *Modern Quantum Chemistry* by Szabo & Ostlund for a good introduction to this topic and for further details, or *Many-Body Methods in Chemistry and Physics* by Shavitt & Bartlett for a more advanced treatment.

This was an example of a strongly correlated closed-shell system. However, open-shell systems (e.g. triplets, or open-shell singlets) are often strongly correlated even around their equilibrium geometry, simply because the correct description of their spin or spatial symmetry is not possible with a single determinant (multiple determinants must be added with the appropriate Clebsch-Gordan coefficients). Transition metal complexes often show such behaviour.

In cases like the above, one must start from a better wave function than RHF. A typical variational approach is to use a small (or at least managable sized) set of determinants to parametrize the ground state:
$$
|\Psi_{\text{opt.}}\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{D}c_i|\Phi_i\rangle \ ,
$$
then build the matrix representation of the Hamiltonian in this space, and diagonalize it (and possibly repeat these steps again and again in an orbital optimizing procedure, since HF orbitals are usually not the best choice anymore). The resulting linear combination of determinants already gives a qualitatively correct starting wave function, on which you can build e.g. perturbative corrections. These methods are collectively called Multi-Reference (MR) methods, and there is a whole zoo of them (and typically each of them comes with their own problems).

To this day, no perfectly satisfactory method has been found for the accurate description of strongly correlated molecules, although an enormous progress has been made.

Answer (score 4):

What is meant by *stringly correlated systems* is not that the correlations are big in comparison to whatever is the characteristic energy, and cannot be calculated using approximate methods, but that these correlations produce behavior that one would not expect from non-interacting system (or weakly interacting system.)

E.g., Ising model in two dimensions and higher could be strongly correlated, because it exhibits a phase transition. (Note that a phase transition takes place regardless of the actual magnitude of the exchange coupling - this magnitude merely affects the temperature of the transition.) Some would suggest that even that is not strong enough - see, e.g., [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77911/247642).

Behavior of atoms and molecules is usually fairly simple - the main difficulty being not conceptual/qualitative, but rather making more precise quantitative predictions of their properties.