Is electron correlation in Quantum Chemistry a consequence of many-body entanglement?
Electron correlation is largely defined in Quantum Chemistry as the set of properties that the celebrated Hartree Fock Approximation cannot model accurately. One popular example is the phenomenon where within the HF approximation, if we take the one-electron density, we (if we the theory were exact) should exhibit a dip near the other electrons, but within the HF scheme it does not, this stems from the fact that HF is inherently a mean-field approximation.
We know that the wave function $\psi(q_1,..,q_n)$ of a non-interacting fermionic system can be represented as $$\psi(q_1,..,q_n)=\hat{A}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}\phi_i(q_i)\right)$$ in the Fock Space - where the $\phi_i$ are the one-particle wavefunctions and $\hat{A}$ is the antisymmetrizer. Is the missing part (the correlation energy) a consequence of the fact that out ansatz above cannot capture the truly many-body entanglement exhibited by the electrons ?

The article arXiv:2403.08045 might be of interest.

Somewhat related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/760191/201598
